# How to distinguish between feature true value 0 and 0 of missing values filling in xgboost?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

How to distinguish between feature true value 0 and 0 of missing values filling in xgboost?
does xgboost equal treat them?

Even you filling missing values with other values x, this question also exist.